# printing 2 characters and keeping them through dynamically allocated 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, string

Hello I am trying to print something like this with 2d array.
Note that when user enters the same number, character should be printed above existing char.

EXPECTED RESULTS:

```
Input 1: 3  //user1 inputs 3

****
****
**x*

Input 2: 1 //user2 inputs 1

****
****
y*x*

Input 3: 1 //user1 inputs 1

****
x***
y*x*
```

current results:

```
enter first: 3
3***
***
**x
enter second: 1
1******
******
xx****
enter first: 2
2*********
*********
***xxx***
```

But keeping printed values on its previous places.
The problem is that they don't get printed in right order. And also it seems that I haven't done the best job with 2d array which is dynamically allocated.
Here is something what I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int num(int term)
{
  int number1;
  int number2;
  if(term==1)
  {
    scanf("%d", &number1);
    return number1;
  }
  if (term==2)
  {
     scanf("%d", &number2);
    return number2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
void function(int a, int b, int result[], int size)
{

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int desired_num = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int *arr[a];

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    arr[i] = (int *)malloc(a * sizeof(int));

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
      arr[i][j] = ++count;

  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
      for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
      {
        if (arr[i][j] == arr[a - 1][result[counter] - 1])
        {
          arr[i][j] = desired_num;
        }

        if (arr[i][j] == desired_num)
        {
          printf("%s", "x");
        }
        else
        {
          printf("*");
        }
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

```
int main()
{
  int counter = 1;
  int i = 0;
  int given_number;
  int array[20];
  for (;;)
  {
    if (counter % 2 != 0)
    {
      printf("enter first: ");
      given_number = num(1);
      printf("%d", given_number);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("enter second: ");
      given_number = num(2);
      printf("%d", given_number);
    }
    array[i] = given_number;
    function(3, 3, array, counter);
    counter++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*But keeping printed values on its spaces*". Please show your code as a [mre], explain what problem it has and describe what debugging you did and what you found.

Comment: @kaylum I thought, keeping values printed where there are every round. Like basically keeping them printed. I've updated code

Comment: Please show your code as well as the exact expected result vs actual result. Please review [ask].

Comment: @kaylum I've just updated it. Edited post. Hope its clearer

Comment: Statements like "keeping printed values on its previous places" are not clear. Please give the exact actual vs expected output.

Comment: @kaylum is anything better now? Ive mentioned exactly wanted output, what Ive tried and current output

Answer (score 0):

```
array[i] = given_number;
```

`i` is never changed from the value of `0`. You are only ever overwriting the first element of `array` each iteration. The other 19 elements remain in an indeterminate state.

`counter` and `array` are passed to `function`, as `size` and `result` respectively:

This means as `size` is incremented, it is used as a bounds for accessing elements of `result`; elements that contain indeterminate values.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
{
    if (arr[i][j] == arr[a - 1][result[counter] - 1])
```

This will surely lead to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) as those indeterminate values are used to index `arr`, effectively accessing random memory offsets. This fact alone makes it hard to reason about the output you are seeing, as really anything is valid.

---

While perfectly valid, the [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) of dynamic allocations is a somewhat perplexing choice, especially considering you fail to `free` the memory allocated by `malloc` when you are done with it.

```
int *arr[a];

for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    arr[i] = (int *)malloc(a * sizeof(int));
```

`int arr[a][b];` would work, given `a` and `b` are not stack-crushingly large values (or non-positive). You are, or would be, bounded by the size of `array` in `main` anyway.

---

The triply nested loop is confused at best. There is only logic for printing the `x` and `*` characters, so you obviously will never see a `y`.

For each element of `arr`, you iterate through each element of `result`. If the current element of `arr` equals the value of the column selected by the current value of `result` (`[result[counter] - 1]`) in the last row (`arr[a - 1]`) you print `x`, otherwise `*`.

Again [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) from utilizing indeterminate values of `result`, but you can see you are printing `a * b * size` characters, plus newlines, each iteration.

This is severely flawed.

---

Some other things of note:

The two branches of the `if .. else` statement in the `num` function do the exact same thing, just with different identifiers.

The two branches of the `if .. else` statement in `main` are identical, other than the first `printf` in each, and the integer value passed to `num`, which have the same effect.

This means the only thing that needs to branch is the `printf` argument.

A generic function for getting an integer would work fine

```
int get_num(void)
{
    int n;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return n;
}
```

for use inside `main`

```
if (counter % 2 == 0)
    printf("enter first: ");
else
    printf("enter second: ");

given_number = get_num();
```

A small issue: `printf("%d", given_number);` is muddling the output slightly.

---

There is no reason to repeatedly generate the array. Initialize an array in `main` to serve as the *state* of the program. Over time, fill it with the users' selections, and simply print the array each iteration.

Make sure to always check the return value of `scanf` is the expected *number of conversions*, and ensure the integers provided by the users will not access invalid memory.

Here is a cursory example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EMPTY '*'
#define PLAYER_ONE 'X'
#define PLAYER_TWO 'O'

int get_num(void)
{
    int n;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    const size_t rows = 6;
    const size_t cols = 7;

    char board[rows][cols + 1];

    memset(board, EMPTY, sizeof board);

    /* our rows are now strings */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        board[i][cols] = '\0';
        puts(board[i]);
    }

    unsigned char turn = 1;

    while (1) {
        printf("Player %s, Enter column #(1-%zu): ",
                turn & 1 ? "One" : "Two", rows);

        int input = get_num();

        if (1 > input || input > cols) {
            printf("Invalid column [%d]. Try again...\n", input);
            continue;
        }

        size_t sel = input - 1;

        if (board[0][sel] != EMPTY) {
            printf("Column [%d] is full! Try again...\n", input);
            continue;
        }

        size_t n = rows;

        while (n--) {
            if (board[n][sel] == EMPTY) {
                board[n][sel] = turn & 1 ? PLAYER_ONE : PLAYER_TWO;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            puts(board[i]);

        turn ^= 1
    }
}
```